# How to pass different child components that implement the common interface to a parent component in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, html-table, architecture, vuejs3

I am looking for a way to render different components inside a table. Each column of the table can include only the same component type.

The main idea what I want to get (**pseudo code**):

App.vue

```
const columns = [
  {
     title: 'Link column',
     component: MyLinkComponent
  },
  {
     title: 'Button column',
     component: MyButtonComponent
  }
]

// MyLinkComponent and MyButtonComponent have different templates and props, 
// but some of props are the same (generic public interface). For example
// they both can have "text" prop, but link can also have "url".


<Table :columns="columns" />
```

Table.vue

```
const props = defineProps({
   columns
})

<template>
  <div v-for="(column, index) in props.columns" :key="column.id">
    <component :is="props.columns[index]" />
  </div>
</template>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the exact problem with the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout the demo, it works fine.
https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your column components [globally or local](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#global-registration):

Ex. Table.vue, please make sure that the components are registered;

```
<template>
  <div 
    v-for="(column, columnIndex) in columns" 
    :key="columnIndex"
  >
    <component :is="column.componentName" v-bind="column.props" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyLinkComponent from '...';
import MyButtonComponent from '...';

export default {
  components: {MyLinkComponent, MyButtonComponent},
  props: {
    columns: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can change the structure of the array to be more readable at Table.vue

App.vue

```
const columns = [
  {
    componentName: 'MyLinkComponent',
    props: {
       title: 'Link column'
     }
  },
  {
    componentName: 'MyButtonComponent',
    props: {
      title: 'Button column'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I use Composition API, so it seems I don't need to register my components.

Comment: Also it is confused me a bit, I need to pass column and column.component separately to generic component. It looks like some kind of passing duplication data.